# Unable to delete wordpress plugin on ubuntu 14.04 VPS

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, ftp, vps

I just installed WordPress in my ubuntu 14.04 VPS server.

But when i delete default plugins then i am getting this message :

**Connection Information**

**To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.**

I have not setup FTP but I have entered FTPS (SSL) details. After that i am getting this message:

**ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.**

Also i have updated permissions 777 to all directory.

Comment: That's too bad. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: Why do you not deactivate and after delete plug-in per ftp?

Comment: No this is not my bad luck. It's ubuntu bad luck. Bcoz i am thinking to leave it. If not solved. But i am working hard to find solution. Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day sir

Comment: @Eugen Yes you are write but i am also unable to update WordPress version. if so, i need to do everything manually via SFTP. But in shared web hosting, we can do same without any problem. Here it's un managed server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is happen because you run your word-press in Ubuntu.this is because ubuntu is very secure.if you run your wordpress in windows you didn't find this kind of problem. i suggest you, you can directly delete your plugin from plugin folder i.e.**"your wordpress folder/wp-content/plugins/".** or you can follow this link:

[More Info](http://vps2.me/avoid-wordpress-asking-ftp-credentials-when-install-upgrade-plugins/)

Comment: Yes Ubuntu is secure but there should be a way to do so.

Comment: @Rinku :yes!! check my "More Info" link in answer.

Comment: Yes i need to set up FTP.